# Android - Layout in the middle of (and over) two other layouts

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm trying to achieve this kind of layout:

[image]

My problem is the middle section. It's basically a framelayout with an image and a text. I want to achieve the round image feeling over both the top layout (the map in this case) and the green layout. The green layout has a bottom gravity and the map has a weight of 1.

Obviously I tried setting the padding of the middle section to as much as the distance from the green layout. This works only for one screen size of course. For others, the middle layout will fall over the green layout, or the map depending on each screen size.

Is it possible to accomplish this kind of design within xml only? I tried having a framelayout and setting the image margin to negative. Problem is that the part of the layout that is "outside the layout" dissapears...

I would really prefer to avoid the activity logic to place the middle layout properly...

Any ideas are welcome. :)

Comment: So the middle part is not always in the middle ? With less text it would be a bit more to the bottom ? Does the white part change in height ?

Comment: I haven't read your answer yet (still no time but today i will :) ) but to answer this comment: The size of the bottom layout is actually dependent on 4 layouts which have fixed sizes (in dp I would say). Still I would rather not give the middle section hard coded paddings. (Like I said, I still have to see answers to see if any help. :)) But thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's based on the assumption that you know the height of the white bar. If you don't, you need to programmatically use the ViewTreeObserver to get the height as soon as possible and set height/2 as a margin.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#00ff00"
        android:padding="12dp"
        android:text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer imperdiet enim vel diam vulputate dapibus. Curabitur consequat faucibus dignissim. Quisque at auctor nulla, ac volutpat dui. Sed pharetra, orci nec volutpat placerat, felis justo dapibus felis, ac vulputate tellus libero id purus. Ut erat risus, fermentum vestibulum urna eu, scelerisque tempus lorem. Proin tincidunt vitae risus id tincidunt. " />
</LinearLayout>

<View
    android:id="@+id/view1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="#0000ff"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
</View>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_above="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:background="#55555555"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_marginBottom="-20dp" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
</LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Using this approach worked :) Thank you very much. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I think you will have to use padding as you suggested but instead of hardcoding the margin you will have to define values in dimen.xml under different values folders.

Comment: Thanks for your ideia. I really want to avoid that because I don't really want to have to know all different screen sizes and hardcode the paddings according to each size. For that I'd rather use activity logic. :/

Answer (score 0):

I'd put views in relative layout like this:

```
<RelativeLayout>
  <top view definition>
  <bottom view definition>
  <text view definition: above bottom view, below top view, align parent right />

  <image view with valid positioning related to text view>
</RelativeLayout>
```

The image view is going to be rendered as the last one so it will cover some part of top view, some part of bottom view and will be exactly in the place you want.